# How to implement ActivityEventListener on my custom module?

Tags: java, react-native, android-intent

I successfully created a custom react native module that allows me to open another app and launch an intent for it. I can’t seem to get the response back onto react native when the opened app finishes what it was doing. I’ve tried using .startActivityForResult() but I run into some issues since my MainActivity is extending the DevMenuAwareActivity and asks for an extra parameter that I can’t seem to get.
I was following this exact thread: Link but ran into the issue when trying to populate the mReactInstanceManager.onActivityResult method.

My MainActivity:

```
private ReactInstanceManager mReactInstanceManager;
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        mReactInstanceManager.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

```
public class PaymentModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements ActivityEventListener {
    private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
    Promise promise;

    public PaymentModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
        this.reactContext.addActivityEventListener(this);

    }


@Override
public String getName() {
    return "PaymentModule";
}




@ReactMethod
    public void openExampleApp(String amount, String messageType, String currencyCode, String currencyFraction, String currencyAlpha, String transactionId){

        try {
 Log.d("PaymentModule", "Trigger openPaxPayment Fn: "+amount);
            this.promise = promise;
        Intent paymentIntent = new Intent("com.my.example.REQUEST");
        paymentIntent.putExtra("MESSAGE_TYPE", messageType);
        paymentIntent.putExtra("AMOUNT", amount);
        paymentIntent.putExtra("CURRENCY_CODE", currencyCode);
        paymentIntent.putExtra("CURRENCY_FRACTION", currencyFraction);
        paymentIntent.putExtra("CURRENCY_ALPHA", currencyAlpha);
        paymentIntent.putExtra("MERCHANT_TRS_ID", transactionId);
           Bundle dataBundle = paymentIntent.getExtras();
        getReactApplicationContext().startActivityForResult(paymentIntent, 8888,dataBundle);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("PaymentModule Err", String.valueOf(e));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        this.promise.resolve(data.getDataString());

    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

I can’t seem to find concrete or clear information on the ActivityEventListener implementation when on bare workflow.

Any tips?